# Get Index on JSOUP not working

Tags: java, android, attributes, jsoup

```
try {
    String url = "http://www.billboard.com/charts/artist-100";
    String urlFound;
    String closing = ")";
    String start = "h";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements urls = doc.getElementsByClass("chart-row__image");
    for (Element u : urls) {
        urlFound = u.attr("style");
        String sub =  urlFound.substring(urlFound.indexOf(start), urlFound.indexOf(closing));
        System.out.println(sub);
        //Log.d("URLS,", attr.substring(attr.indexOf("http://"), attr.indexOf(")")));
    }
}
catch(IOException ex){
}
```

I tried debugging this several times, but I keep getting the error, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1` I' m not sure why this happening either? Can someone give me an idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're extracting the style attribute Strings from all the `div class="chart-row__image` elements, but understand that many elements in this group don't have a style attribute. In this situation JSoup is returning an empty String, and this is messing up your program. The solution is not to do this but instead to let jsoup select only those elements that have a style attribute.

For instance, not:

```
Elements urls = doc.getElementsByClass("chart-row__image");
```

but rather:

```
Elements urls = doc.select(".chart-row__image[style]");
```

And yeah, don't ignore exceptions.

So

```
    String url = "http://www.billboard.com/charts/artist-100";
    String urlFound;
    String closing = ")";
    String start = "h";
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        // Elements urls = doc.getElementsByClass("chart-row__image");
        Elements urls = doc.select(".chart-row__image[style]");
        for (Element u : urls) {
            urlFound = u.attr("style");
            int startingIndex = urlFound.indexOf(start);
            int endingIndex = urlFound.indexOf(closing);
            if (startingIndex > 0 && endingIndex > 0) {
                String sub = urlFound.substring(startingIndex, endingIndex);
                System.out.println(sub);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```